# Rails Tutorial: Redefining the BCrypt cost factor in a test environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, railstutorial.org

I am new to Rails and following the Ruby on Rails Tutorial by Michael hartl.

After following Listing 7.11, Redefining the BCrypt cost factor in a test environment:

```
#config/environments/test.rb
SampleApp::Application.configure do
.
.
.
# Speed up tests by lowering BCrypt's cost function. 
require 'bcrypt'
  silence_warnings do
    BCrypt::Engine::DEFAULT_COST = BCrypt::Engine::MIN_COST
  end
end
```

I receive these warnings each time I run Rspec:

```
/Users/stonefruit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/bcrypt-ruby-3.0.1/lib/bcrypt.rb:28: warning: already initialized constant DEFAULT_COST
/Users/stonefruit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/bcrypt-ruby-3.0.1/lib/bcrypt.rb:30: warning: already initialized constant MIN_COST
/Users/stonefruit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/bcrypt-ruby-3.0.1/lib/bcrypt.rb:32: warning: already initialized constant MAX_SALT_LENGTH
```

May I know if these warnings are important? Also, is the 'silence_warnings' supposed to do anything to the warnings?

Thanks!

Edit: there was a typo in the listing I provided. Moved require 'bcrypt' out of the commented line.

Edited with answer:

While editing the post, I found out I had not followed the listing exactly. In my code, I had used

```
require 'BCrypt'
```

instead of

```
require 'bcrypt'
```

The warnings disappeared after changing it to all lowercase!

Comment: I'm glad your sorted that out!

Comment: Thanks deivid. I'm not sure if I am supposed to tick your comment because it does not seem to be the real answer to the question. Can you guide me on how it works on stackoverflow please?

Comment: I am pretty new to Stackoverflow as well, but I think you are right. You actually found the answer to your own question! I'm not sure what the standard procedure is here... but I think I'll remove my answer as it doesn't add any value.